# Images not showing (bootstrap)

Tags: image, twitter-bootstrap, model-view-controller, twitter

Kindly help me on what to do. The problem I'm facing right now is I am having difficulty on combining bootstrap with ASP.net MVC4. The CSS is working, but unfortunately, images aren't showing on the carousel, or any other part of the webpage.

[image: Homepage]

Code is:
[Code used](https://www.dropbox.com/s/g8dq7i2qa3jpnq2/code.txt?dl=0)

The prior steps I did before doing this is: 
1. Installed bootstrap using Nuget. 
2. Confirmed that the source of my images, is working, only that,
when I insert in within bootstrap code, it doesn't work. 
3. Cleared all files, restarted visual studio. 
4. I also checked for the paths of the image and searched
it on stackoverflow and google. 
Links I used: 

[Next and previous images in carousel not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16131056/show-next-and-previous-image-in-twitter-bootstrap-carousel) 
[Twitter bootstrap images not showing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10362093/twitter-bootstrap-images-not-showing)

Help is greatly appreciated. Thank you! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try call img like this

```
<img alt="" src="@Url.Content("~/Images/Cover/6.jpg")" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should remove the ~ symbol in front of your img's src attributes